# Correct use of Histogram Data - Setting interval size?

Tags: histogram, anylogic

In my model, I am saving results from numerous `Parameter Variation` runs in a `Histogram Data` object.

Here are my `Histogram Data` settings:

```
Number of intervals: 7
Value range:
     Automatically detected
     Initial Interval Size: 10
```

I then print out these results using the following :

```
//if final replication, write Histogram Data into Excel
if(getCurrentReplication() == lastReplication){
    double intervalWidth = histogramData.getIntervalWidth();
    int intervalQty = histogramData.getNumberOfIntervals();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < intervalQty; i++){
        traceln(intervalWidth*i + " " + histogramData.getPDF(i));
        excelRecords.setCellValue(String.valueOf(intervalWidth*i) + " - " + String.valueOf(intervalWidth*(i+1)), 1, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        excelRecords.setCellValue(histogramData.getPDF(i), 1, rowIndex, columnIndex+1);
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

Example of my intended results:

```
10 - 80%
20 - 10%
30 - 5%
40 - 2%
50...
60...
```

Actual results:

```
0.0 0.0
10.0 0.0
20.0 0.0
30.0 0.998782775272379
40.0 0.0011174522089635631
50.0 9.9772518657461E-5
60.0 0.0
```

Results after settings initial interval size to 0.1:

```
0.0 0.9974651710510558
4.0 0.001117719851502934
8.0 9.181270208774101E-4
12.0 2.3951139675062872E-4
16.0 1.5967426450041916E-4
20.0 9.979641531276197E-5
24.0 0.0
```

How would I go about obtaining my desired results? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about the `HistogramData` object?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using (getPDF(i)) returns value for the interval in fractions (not in percentages). So, you have to multiply the value by 100 in order to get it as a percentage. As for histogram bars, model analyze the results, specified interval numbers and interval size. After that, it will build the respective number of bars that cover all results. In your case, intervals from 0 to 30 do not provide any results and bars are not presented (PDF here is 0.0).

Comment: I understand that getPDF resturns the results for the interval in fraction. Me putting percentages in my desired answer was just as an indication. You can see in my "Results after settings initial interval size to 0.1" that there are clearly results for 0 and 4 (if you read my code, these represent intervals 0 to 4 and 4 to 8). These results should have been under the 0 to 10 interval in my "Actual results", and they are not. I know that AnyLogic will automatically build the required number of bars depending on the number of intervals I specify - but I want to set my own width.